# pass by reference with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

If I mutate the value of `myArray` within `myFunction`, the new `myArray` is updated:

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log( JSON.stringify(myArray) ); // [1, 2, 3]

function myFunction(arr) {
  arr.push(4);
  console.log( JSON.stringify(arr) ); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  return arr;
}

myFunction(myArray);
console.log( JSON.stringify(myArray) ); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

However, if I try to reassign `myArray` with `arr = [0];` within `myFunction`, `myArray` stays the same.

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log( JSON.stringify(myArray) );; // [1, 2, 3]

function myFunction(arr) {
  arr = [0];
  console.log( JSON.stringify(arr) ); // [0]
  return arr;
}

myFunction(myArray);
console.log( JSON.stringify(myArray) ); // [1, 2, 3]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Why can't `myArray` be reassigned in the example above, but can be if I do this:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
myArray = [0];
console.log(myArray); // [0]
```

Comment: Quoting Wiki's ["call by sharing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) section: _Mutations of arguments performed by the called routine will be visible to the caller [but] it is not possible to simulate an assignment on that variable in the callee's scope_.

Comment: JavaScript does not have "pass by reference" so the parameter `arr` is a different variable than the variable `myArray`, so assigning something `arr` does not affect `myArray`. `arr` holds a reference/pointer/linkage to the array and that one is passed by value, so `arr` and `myArray` point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing the addressing linked to the internal elements of the array with the addressing of the array itself

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
```

create in memory an array object with `[1, 2, 3]`
and give his address on `myArray` variable

```
function myFunction(arr)
```

create a new variable named `arr`
with a copy of the address of `myArray` variable

---

---

in the same way you have:

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3]
let arr     = myArray

arr = [0]
 
console.log( JSON.stringify(myArray) ) // [1, 2, 3]
console.log( JSON.stringify(arr) )     // [0]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your example you're not actually reassigning `myArray`. You'd need to do `myArray = myFunction(myArray)`.

Comment: The OP assumes that `myArray` is passed by reference (which it is not), and if that would be the case then `arr` would just be a reference to `myArray`, so assigning to `arr` would also change `myArray`. That's a misconception that happens quite often.